# Variable index with bitfield instruction BFI in Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

With the arm BFI instruction we can set bits at a specified position but the  position is fix. How can this be done more flexible:

```
BFI.w R0, r1, #1, #4 // <lsb>, <width>
```

If you have the value
0b01001000 and you insert 0b0011(widht 4) at 1(lsb) the result is 0b1000110.

How can I use this BFI in a function that the position of lsb is given by a register like:

```
BFI.w R0, r1, **r2**, #4 // <lsb>, <width>
```

I know that this can be done with other instructions but each other solution cost further instructions and this is not the goal.

Comment: You can always manually OR with a shifted group of bits.  Try writing it in C++ for a function like `return x | (0b1111 << pos);` and look at optimized compiler output (https://godbolt.org/) and see what GCC or clang come up with.

Comment: It seems for me that you doesnt know what the BFI does.

Comment: Perhaps you want `BFX` instead?  Can you give an example of what you mean by “I want the value of lsb(#1) in a register?”  Also, please don't ask if something is possible unless you are looking for a proof that it is not.  In computing, most things are possible.  Some just require a lot of effort to do.  Instead ask “how do I ...?” if you want to know how to do something.

Comment: You said you only wanted to *set* bits at specified positions.  I assumed you meant "turn them on", but apparently you meant "replace their values".  The simple / naive way to handle that would be to `AND` with a mask first to clear all the bits in the range, then OR to set the ones you wanted set.  Anyway, you're correct, I didn't remember or look up what BFI did, but writing an equivalent function in C always works if you know what you want.

Comment: Why do you think that I search for a solution with AND, OR or something. I said clearly that I want to use BFI and not any other instruction.

Comment: If you write it in the C source in a simple way, an optimizing compiler might show you how to do it with an instruction or two you didn't think of.  That was the key point of my suggestion, and still applies.

Comment: Someone who writes code for arm cortex and asks questions about assembly always see the assembly code made from C and also have the optimization in hand.